# XElement value in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

How to get a value of `XElement` without getting child elements?

An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<someNode>
    someValue
    <child>1</child>
    <child>2</child>
</someNode>
```

If i use XElement.Value for `<someNode>` I get `"somevalue<child>1</child><child>2<child>"` string but I want to get only "somevalue" without `"<child>1</child><child>2<child>"` substring.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it slightly more simply than using `Descendants` - the `Nodes` method only returns the direct child nodes:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(
    @"<someNode>somevalue<child>1</child><child>2</child></someNode>");
var firstTextValue = element.Nodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value;
```

Note that this will work even in the case where the child elements came *before* the text node, like this:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(
    @"<someNode><child>1</child><child>2</child>some value</someNode>");
var firstTextValue = element.Nodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value;
```

Comment: If I want to get the value of all the nodes do I need to necessarily iterate the list of nodes? I'm interested in the values of the nodes that are not of type XText

Comment: @BBHorus: Well if you want to look at all the nodes, then yes, you need to iterate over them. It's really not clear what you're trying to do - you might want to add a new question.

Comment: Oh never mind now I realized that I do need some of the text nodes but the first and last. I have this element: 
<package>package <name>com</name>.<name>sample</name>.<name>app1</name>;</package>

What I want is a value like this: com.sample.app1, I think I need to use some regex or something else like iterate the child nodes and get only the elements skipping the first and last ones.

Comment: @BBHorus: You should almost *certainly* not use a regular expression. It's almost *always* the wrong approach to XML handling.

Comment: Not to the XML is to the value in the XML element, it always contains these two parts: starts with "package ", and ends with ";" those I don't want but the rest of it. Thank you for your clarifications and help

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way. You'll have to iterate and select. For instance:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(
    @"<someNode>somevalue<child>1</child><child>2</child></someNode>");
var textNodes = from node in doc.DescendantNodes()
                where node is XText
                select (XText)node;
foreach (var textNode in textNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(textNode.Value);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. In my program I'm needed in full enumeration of xml nodes and changes every values. With your sample I'm not needed in a recursive enum of xml nodes.

Comment: @MaxFX: This will still recursively enumerate all nodes within the element though. It's hidden, but it's still happening. See my answer for a way of avoiding that.

Comment: You can simply write var textNodes = doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>();

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want would be the first descendant node, so something like:

```
var value = XElement.Descendents.First().Value;
```

Where `XElement` is the element representing your `<someNode>` element.

You can specifically ask for the first text element (which is "somevalue"), so you could also do:

```
var value = XElement.Descendents.OfType<XText>().First().Value;
```