# Update elements using LINQ to XML?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have the following XML, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to update the elements directly using LINQ to XML:

```
XElement settings = XElement.Parse (
@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
                  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
                  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'    
                  xmlns:wsa='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing'
                  xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' 
                  xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand='1'> 
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken-72135529'> 
        <wsse:Username>{USERNAME}</wsse:Username> 
        <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>{PASSWORD}</wsse:Password> 
    </wsse:UsernameToken> 
 </wsse:Security> 
    <wsa:MessageID>{MESSAGEID}</wsa:MessageID> 
    <wsa:To>{TO}</wsa:To> 
    <wsa:Action>{ACTION}</wsa:Action> 
    <wsa:From> 
    <wsa:Address>{ADDRESS}</wsa:Address> 
</wsa:From> 
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
{BODY}
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>");
```

For example, in the above, I want to access each element that has placholder value `{}` and update the text.  Is doing `XElement.Parse()` correct in this scenario?  I am most likely going to load it into and `XDocument` first and then update the elements.  Also, how could I update attributes, like the Type attribute on `Password`?

Trying to get to Username, but it says it is an InvalidOperationException.

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace wsa = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing";
XNamespace wsse = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
XNamespace wsu = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";

var textElement = settings.Elements(xmlns + "Envelope").
                           Elements(xmlns + "Header").
                           Elements(wsse + "Security").
                           Elements(wsse + "UsernameToken").
                           Elements(wsse + "Username").Single();
```

Also, is it just me or does using XPath seem simpler if I know the exact position of the elements and if I wanted to update or remove xmlns:wsa for example, how would that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it

```
var elements = settings.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().Where(p => p.Value.StartsWith("{") && p.Value.EndsWith("}"));

foreach (var node in elements)
{
    // This is an example of manipulation. It will simply remove the {}
    node.Value = node.Value.Substring(1, node.Value.Length - 2);
}
```

You could move the `Where` condition directly in the for cycle, like

```
var elements = settings.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>();

foreach (var node in elements.Where(p => p.Value.StartsWith("{") && p.Value.EndsWith("}")))
{
    // This is an example of manipulation. It will simply remove the {}
    node.Value = node.Value.Substring(1, node.Value.Length - 2);
}
```

The instruction for finding `XText` nodes are from [XElement value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224417/xelement-value-in-c-sharp)

Note that you'll need to add the missing namespaces:

```
xmlns:wsse='something' xmlns:wsa='somethingelse' xmlns:wsu='somethingelseelse'
```

or the `XElement.Parse` will break;

If you want to update a single element of which you know the name:

```
XNamespace wsa = "somethingelse"; // Here you must put the namespace!

var textElement = settings.Descendants(wsa + "MessageID").Single(); // If there is only one Message ID to change (0 or > 1 MessageID will make Single throw), .First() if you are only interested in the first one
textElement.Value = "MessageID"; // Changed!
```

or

```
var textElements = settings.Descendants(wsa + "MessageID") // If there are multipleMessage ID to change

foreach (var textElement in textElements)
{
    textElement.Value = "MessageID"; // Changed!
}
```

Be aware that these variants will change the first/all the wsa:MessageID, ignoring their position.

or if you know the exact "path" to your node, use something like

```
var textElements = settings.Elements(name1).Elements(name2)...
```

and then use the `Single()`, the `.First()` or the `foreach`

A small sample code:

```
XElement settings = XElement.Parse(
@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:wsa='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing' xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand='1'> 
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken-72135529'> 
                <wsse:Username>{USERNAME}</wsse:Username> 
                <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>{PASSWORD}</wsse:Password> 
            </wsse:UsernameToken> 
        </wsse:Security> 
        <wsa:MessageID>{MESSAGEID}</wsa:MessageID> 
        <wsa:To>{TO}</wsa:To> 
        <wsa:Action>{ACTION}</wsa:Action> 
        <wsa:From> 
            <wsa:Address>{ADDRESS}</wsa:Address> 
        </wsa:From> 
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        {BODY}
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>");


var soapenv = settings.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("soapenv");
var wsa = settings.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("wsa");
var wsse = settings.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("wsse");
var wsu = settings.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("wsu");

XElement username = settings.Elements(soapenv + "Header").Elements(wsse + "Security").Elements(wsse + "UsernameToken").Elements(wsse + "Username").Single();
Console.WriteLine(username);
username.Value = "NewValue";
Console.WriteLine(username);
```

Comment: I will know the placeholder elements at design time, so if I just wanted to get the {USERNAME} element, how would I do that? and in turn replace {USERNAME} with the actual value.

Comment: A couple of points.  I have the namespaces already declared,  I just omitted them for the example, so I do have wsa, wsu, wsse.  I also do know the exact placement of the elements.  I am curious as to why I need to declare the namespace and I tried to do something like: `settings.Elements("Header").Elements("Security").Elements("UsernameToken").Elements("Username").Single()`, but it said Sequence contains no elements

Comment: When I do your example, I get "Sequence contains no elements as well" XNamespace wsa = "xmlns:wsa='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"; var textElement = settings.Descendants(wsa + "MessageID").Single();

Comment: @Xaisoft Because the real name of `Header` is `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Header` (or something similar... in XML you always use the abbreviations you define, so soapenv:Header). It's like (in C#) trying to use the class `Console` without inserting the `using System` or referencing it by its full name (for example `System.Console`). In XLinq you can use the full namespaces if you want. It would be `{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Header` but it's quite verbose, so you use the `XNamespace` class.

Comment: ok I got you that clears that part up, I'm still a little confused about getting directly to the elements or attributes if I know the exact path.

Comment: @Xaisoft It didn't find anything because the element names you gave him were "wrong". They didn't contain the namespace.

Comment: You noticed my comment "// Here you must put the namespace!"? :-)

Comment: Ah... And Header is a child of Envelope :-) You can't skip elements in your chain.

Comment: Ok, let me add the XNamespaces and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I still got an error, I am probably doing something wrong, I will update the xml I have with the everything and show you what I am trying to do in a code snippet.

Comment: @Xaisoft I was wrong. You mustn't put a Element("Envelope"). The `settings` XElement is already the element Envelope. A sample of code that works is http://pastebin.com/AXu0defa

Comment: In the pasted example I use the `Element` instead of `Elements`. Clearly it returns a single element instead of an `IEnumerable`, but you were asking for a single field in a single position in this case.

Comment: OK, after looking at your comment with using Element, it wokred.  Thanks for the patience and help.  Thanks for pointing out settings.GetNamespaceOfPrefix as well.

Comment: The new sample code works with the xml you pasted (I found the namespaces on google. They are "standard" ones)

Comment: Do you think XPath is simpler if the exact location is known?

Comment: @Xaisoft For *this* type of work no. In the end you are only writing some Element("") that in XPath you wouldn't write. You lose some characters.

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that I can just use the local names without having to declare the namespaces by doing the following:

```
XElement user = settings.Descendants().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName == "Username").Single();
```