# How to update multiple attributes on a collection?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

With a LINQ-to-XML query, I have a collection of `elements` (type `IEnumerable<XElement>`) and on this collection, I want to update all values of a specific attribute.  All updated values can be the same.

Take `elements` containing these elements:

```
<element attribute1="value11" attribute2="value21" attribute3="value31" />
<element attribute1="value21" attribute2="value22" attribute3="value33" />
<element attribute1="value31" attribute2="value23" attribute3="value33" />
```

On `elements`, how to update all values of `attribute1` at the same time?

Comment: you can select all elements and use a foreach selecting each attribute, you can set the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq is used for querying. To set all values you should probably iterate:

I haven´t tested this but I think something like this should do the trick:

```
var elements = document.Descendants("element");

foreach (XElement e in elements)
{
 if (element.Attribute("attribute1") != null)
        element.Attribute("attribute1").Value = "whateverValue";
    else
        element.Add(new XAttribute("attribute1", "whateverValue"));
}
```

Related: 
[Update elements using LINQ to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813378/update-elements-using-linq-to-xml)